# IP routing devices with security

Tags: networking, routing

I'm looking for a device that we can use to do routing between various IP ranges on our network, but offer us some security as to which devices can communicate where.

Existing network has 2 major zones "Admin" and "Control". On the "Control" side there are multiple IP Ranges which were on separate VLANs connected into a switch.

We would like to put in some sore of routing/firewall device that allows us to route between the VLAN/IPRanges and specify which devices can connect to where (e.g. Server on 10.10.138.10 can access ONLY Device on 192.168.50.35)

Any ideas where to start looking for a device, What would it be called? Looking for something that is simple to configure (We currently use a Cyberoam UTM, which has a nice GUI for rules, but would like something simpler without the Web filter, etc.)

This image represents what the network layout looks like.

[image]

Comment: If what you have does the job, keep it that way.  You may think there is a magical device that does things as simply as you described them but there is no psychic device that can guess the missing details that the GUI you have asks you whether you like it or not.  A device that does routing and firewalling is called a router and the one you're looking for needs advanced configurations to deal with this setup.

Comment: You could roll your own thing with linux, but of it is a a lot of work.  Maybe you could experiment with PF Sense.

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close as this is a hardware recommendation.  You are probably getting out of the realm of "GUI Driven" devices - I'd put together a Linux box, bind that to a VLAN Capable switch for multiple ports and use IPTables to control the routing though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It was requested we get an alternative device to our current as they want it to be standalone. Although GUI would be nice, it isn't a requirement. The "roll your own" discussion was had but would like to investigate alternatives.

Comment: Have a look at [Dell SonicWall](http://www.sonicwall.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Any enterprise router is able to satisfy your requirement. Simple ACL would achieve your goal. As a CCIE, I would prefer cisco device personally.

> We currently use a Cyberoam UTM, which has a nice GUI for rules

GUI is not a good idea for me. Normally, it is not so stable if we involve GUI and also, it is not good for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. The GUI is more to allow our Manager to be feel comfortable with the process of adding/updating ACL rules. What Cisco would you suggest (as a starting point)

Comment: It really depends on your requirement. To find the device which is more suitable for you, I would suggest you to consult with the local dealer about this case.